# Easy interactive visualization of orbital elements

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbital-elements, artificial-satellite, software, universe-sandbox

To get a grip on orbital elements, I'd like to play with a ready interactive visualization like in [Universe Sandbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universe_Sandbox). E.g. drag the inclination slider and see immediately what happens to the satellite orbit. Are there any free tools capable of doing this? I wasn't able to find such a function in [Celestia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celestia) or [Stellarium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellarium_(software)) so far.

[image: screen shot of Universe Sandbox orbit UI]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you need is a quick and free tool to visualize orbits around earth, websites such as the following might be enough:

First, the very simple [orbitalmechanics.info](https://orbitalmechanics.info/), where you can just ignore the "add launch" option:
[image]

And then, the more artsy [Harmony-of-the-Spheres](https://thehappykoala.github.io/Harmony-of-the-Spheres/), which can also visualize some other systems.
[image]

Maybe that already helps.